# Stripe Webhook issue in Next js 14

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments, webhooks

When a stripe payment session is completed successfully, the webhook route is supposed to trigger and save the order details in database but the webhook is not working properly, The response from webhook is like -- **HTTP status code
307 (Temporary Redirect)
Redirecting...**

*I have already checked the endpoint is correct and also the payment session is completed in stripe dashboard*

> Image of api end point of stripe dashboard is attached

The **route.ts** file in `/api/webhook`:

```js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import Stripe from "stripe";
import prismadb from "@/lib/prismadb";
      
export async function POST(req: Request) {
  const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY!,{
    apiVersion:"2023-10-16"
  });
    
  const body = await req.text();
    
  const stripeSignature = req.headers.get("stripe-signature") as string;
    
  const endPointSecret = process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET as string;
    
  let stripeEvent;
    
  try {
    stripeEvent = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
      body,
      stripeSignature,
      endPointSecret
    );
   } catch (error) {
      return NextResponse.json({ msg: "Webhook error", error });
   }
    
   const eventType = stripeEvent.type;
    
   if (eventType === "checkout.session.completed") {
      const session = stripeEvent.data.object; //!session contains the metadata of the event and the buyer,the price and the stripeId
    
      const metadata = session.metadata; //`At the time of checkout we stored the eventId and the buyerId in the metadata of the session
    
      const orderData = {
          eventId: metadata?.eventId || "",
          buyerId: metadata?.buyerId || "",
          price: (session.amount_total! / 100).toString(),
          stripeId: session.id,
      };
    
      try {
          const newOrder = await prismadb.order.create({
            data: {
              buyerId: orderData.buyerId,
              eventId: orderData.eventId,
              totalAmount: orderData.price,
              stripeId: orderData.stripeId,
            },
          });
          console.log(newOrder)
          return NextResponse.json({ status: 200, newOrder });
      } catch (error) {
          console.log("Error createOrderDB", error);
          return NextResponse.json({ status: 500, error: "Internal Server Error" });
      }
 
      }

      return new Response("", { status: 200 });
    }
```

I tried changing the endpoint and correcting it , it was correct already
I tried running on local network but the response from webhook was same

Comment: This redirect code is happening when Stripe tries to reach out to your server. It likely doesn't have anything to do with the status of the stripe payment itself. I don't see redirect logic in your code, so it sounds like this redirect is coming at an earlier step. If Stripe is trying to reach out to a URL that you provided, it sounds like your server tries to redirect from there to somewhere else. In that case you will need to either change your config so that that URL directly responds rather than redirecting or you can give Stripe the URL that that redirect is going to.

Comment: Yep, i forgot to add webhook in ignored routes of clerk authentication middleware

Answer (score 0):

The redirecting issue was not related to stripe but clerk auth, I overlooked the route settings in clerk middleware -
When I changed the folder for stripe webhook route.ts, I forgot to change the API route in the middleware file for ignored Routes, `ignoredRoutes: ["/api/edgestore/init","/api/webhook","/api/webhooks"]`,
After adding the route my problem was fixed and I received the status `200` instead of Redirecting.. in the webhook response.